# What windows form component would best be used to create a log file viewer C#

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, tail

I have a quick question. Really appreciate any help.

I'm planning to create a simple log file view in c#. A windows form will display the content of a log file. The form will periodically update to view the latest logs and will always scroll down to the latest log.

Which windows form component would best be used to create such view?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `GridView` if planning to parse and decompose the log content or a simple multiline `TextBox` if you plan to do not parse log content and simply show it.

about Grids, I like the DevExpress XtraGrid which has tons of features and is highly customizable (if you need advanced features, no code excel/pdf export, print preview, send via email etc....)

about text boxes, this is surely the best and has so many features.... [ScintillaNet](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is this the standard datagridview in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to implement is a equivalent of a tail command in UNIX.

There are a couple of tools some of them are free which you would want to use -

- [LogExpert](http://logexpert.codeplex.com/)  - Free and open source solution
- http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

**LogExpert** which is an opensource tail command implementation uses a `GridView`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the content of the log.

If entries are single lines of text, a multi-line text box would be OK.

If entries are more complex a ListView might be better.

Comment: why to use a ListView like a grid instead of a GridView?

Comment: Because I don't need the features to add, edit, sort etc. that are available in a GridView. If you need them, use a GridView.

Comment: a ListView still is not a Grid and handling of columns and "rows" is not as easy as in a Grid, even without sorting, filtering or paging.

Comment: Just set it to details view. Adding lines/items is easy.

Answer (score 1):

This definately depends on the information in the log file. The most simple control is your `TextBox` control.

If you want some colour in the mix, use the `RichTextBox` control.

If you have specific information in your log file, use the `GridView` control.